# Is PUSHQ POPFQ the most direct way to set flags on x86_64?

Tags: assembly

Is:

```
PUSHQ %reg
POPFQ
```

the most direct way to set flags on x86_64?

Comment: Some flags have direct set instructions, e.g `stc`, refer to the intel instruction set for others.

Comment: Flags are implicitly set by many instructions. It depends very much on the situation. There is no general, "most direct way."

Comment: I'm not sure that I see how this is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the flag.

Some of the flags allow you to set the bit directly.  For example, `STC` to set the carry flag and `CLC` to clear the carry flag.  If you want to manipulate, say, the Trap Flag, you must do something like this (assuming NASM and 16 bit assembly):

```
pushf
pop   ax
or    ax, 0x100
push  ax
popf
```

Of course, you can also set or clear flags indirectly.  For example:

```
xor   ax, ax
```

This code, most directly, sets ax to zero through an XOR.  Indirectly, it has the side effect of setting both the ZF (zero flag) and the PF (parity flag).  Similar types of indirect ways of manipulating the flags are generally available for most of the flag bits.

I would add, as an aside, that the mechanism that you are using in your question could have unintended consequences.  It is much better practice to push the flags, modify the particular flags that you are interested in, and to then pop the flags.  Arbitrarily popping specific values into the flags could create havoc unless you are absolutely certain that there will be no ramifications of changing them (i.e., no code further down is relying on a flag from above).

Comment: Indeed, my application is to restore a previously saved state of flags.

Comment: Ah, that would be a special case then.  What you describe is, indeed, the correct method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just do `pushfq; orq $0x100,(%rsp); popfq` instead of explicitly loading and storing?

Comment: Sure, @fuz, but this is usually something that you need to do once in a while rather than millions of times in a loop, so I'm not sure it's worth the optimization.